# Align Legend Title in tmap

Tags: r, tmap

Is it possible to center the legend title in `tmap`? Utilizing the first example from the [tmap getting started vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-getstarted.html):

```
library(tmap)
data("World")

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI")
```

yields

[image]

but I want:

[image]

I have scoured the documentation for `tm_layout` but can't figure out how to align the text of the legend title. It seems that the only options for `legend.title` in `tm_layout` are (1) `legend.title.color`, (2) `legend.title.size`, (3) `legend.title.fontface`, and (4) `legend.title.fontfamily`, none of which control the alignment. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Would it work if you turned the title off and used `text` to write the title? Hackish, but whatcanyoudo? :)

Answer (score 1):

Well... aparently there is not an argument to control the location of the legend title, have you considered report this as an issue?

A workaround though could be:

```
library(tmap)
data("World")

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI", 
              title = "     HPI")
```

Yes, I know how ugly this looks, but it gets you the result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Orlando - this has been my workaround for now. I will report this as an issue.